# JavaScript + numjs - fill array with slices

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, graphics

I want to make a simple graphics library in JavaScript and numjs. I like python's slices, so I decided to use this library.
I want to fill a rect and get a flattened array like that: [r, g, b, a, r, g, b, a, ...]
My array is:

```js
this.img = nj.ones([width, height, 4], "uint8").multiply(255);
```

I have this code:

```js
this.img = this.img.slice([null, null], [null, null], [3]).assign(b)
this.img = this.img.slice([null, null], [null, null], [2]).assign(g)
this.img = this.img.slice([null, null], [null, null], [1]).assign(r)
```

For now, it translates to python code like that (if I understand it correctly):

```python
img[:,:,:3] = b
img[:,:,:2] = g
img[:,:,:1] = r
```

which is not the most efficient.
I wanted to write in numjs something like that in Python:

```python
img[:,:,:3] = [r,g,b]
```

which results in flattened array:

```text
[r g b 0 r g b 0 ...]
```

If I try to write something like that in numjs:

```js
this.img = this.img.slice([null, null], [null, null], [null, 3]).assign([1,2,3]);
```

I get an error:

```text
jquery-3.6.0.js:4059 Uncaught Error: cwise: Arrays do not all have the same dimensionality!
```

Is there a way to do it in numjs like in Python? If it's not possible, maybe is there a better way to do that (or other JavaScript library)? I don't want to use built-in canvas capabilities.

Edit:
numjs documentation: https://openbase.com/js/numjs/documentation

Edit 2:
this is what happened when I tried:

```
this.img = this.img.slice([y, y + h], [x, x + w], [null, 1]).assign(0)
this.img = this.img.slice([y, y + h], [x, x + w], [1, 2]).assign(0)
```

[this is what happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPyQr.png)

Comment: first you could add link to numjs so we could see documentation. Did you try to use `..., [null, null]).assign([1,2,3, 0]);`? Maybe it use different indexes and it may need `[null,2]` or `[null,4]` ? (PL: może `numjs` używa innej numeracji indeksów i wymaga `[null,2]` alob `[null,4]`?)

Comment: I tried ```this.img = this.img.slice([y, y + h], [x, x + w], [null, null]).assign([r, g, b, 255])``` but it's the same error

Comment: it seems it doesn't have this functionality. If slice gives array with shape `[10,10,3]` then you have to assign array with the same shape `[10,10,3]`. You will have to replace every value `R`, `G`, `B` separatelly.

Comment: BTW: in [source code](https://github.com/nicolaspanel/numjs/tree/master/src/images) you can see functions to work with images but I don't see any method to change values in slice. I see it use some external modules `ndarray-ops` and `cwise` and maybe they have some functions to do it "wisely".